# How can I get error stacktrace in Mojolicious?

Tags: xml, perl, stack-trace, mojolicious

I have some xml parsing procedure in my controller (performed by `XML::LibXML::Simple`)

During page render I got and error

[image]

and there is no "tap for more" link with stacktrace, which mojolicious produces usually when face with `die` in external module (below is example)

[image]

Why it's not getting stacktrace and how can I get stacktrace manually?

I tried to insert

```
use Carp;
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
   app->log->error("Stacktrace: ". Carp::longmess($_[0]) );
};
```

in my app, but no output was produced

Comment: This looks like an unfortunate interaction with the error reporting in XML::LibXML which I've had lots of trouble with in the past. Parsing errors are reported from the XS code probably as a XML::LibXML::Error object, so they don't get wrapped by a Mojo::Exception (which is what provides the stacktrace) and they don't report the filename (the number at the beginning is the line number).

Comment: It's the line number in the XML data that is being parsed, not in the code that does the parsing though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get stack trace manually by calling:

```
$e->frames([$frame1, $frame2]);
```

See [documentaion](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Exception#frames)

where `$e` is `Mojo::Exception` object